# Proving that $\int_{1}^{e}\frac{1+x^2\ln x}{x+x^2\ln x}dx=e-\ln (1+e)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Prove that $\int_{1}^{e}\frac{1+x^2\ln x}{x+x^2\ln x}dx=e-\ln (1+e)$

---

My attempt:
$$I=\int_{1}^{e}\frac{1+x^2\ln x}{x+x^2\ln x}=\int_{1}^{e}\frac{1+x^2\ln x}{x(1+x\ln x)}dx$$
Let $\ln x=e^t$:
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+te^{2t}}{(1+te^t)}dt$$

I cannot solve further.

Comment: I think you meant $x=e^t$, not $\ln x$ (or else $\ln x=t$ instead of $e^t$)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

The indefinite integral can be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Prove that:

$$\frac {1+x^2\ln (x)}{x+x^2\ln(x)}=1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\ln (x)+1}{x\ln (x)+1}$$

Now, the only non-trivial integral we need to solve is:
$$\int \frac{\ln (x)+1}{x\ln (x)+1}~dx$$
To solve it, substitute $u=x\ln (x)+1$.

Comment: Wait how did you prove that equation?? $\frac {1+x^2\ln (x)}{x+x^2\ln(x)}=1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\ln (x)+1}{x\ln (x)+1}$  ??

Comment: @RiRi Note that by adding and subtracting $x$ in the numerator
$$\frac{1+x^2\ln(x)}{x+x^2\ln(x)}=\frac{(x^2\ln(x)+x)+(1-x)}{x+x^2\ln(x)}=1+\frac{1-x}{x+x^2\ln(x)}.$$
Furthermore, by adding and subtracting $x\ln(x)$ in the numerator
$$\frac{1-x}{x+x^2\ln(x)}=\frac{(1+x\ln(x))-(x+x\ln(x))}{x+x^2\ln(x)}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1+\ln(x)}{x\ln(x)+1}.$$

Comment: Got it, thnx a lot!!