# Evaluate the following integral: $ \int \frac{1+x^2 \ln x}{x+x^2 \ln x}dx $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I've just learnt integration recently and I'm having trouble where to start solving it. Evidently this can't be solved with direct substitution (atleast in my knowledge) and I think I'm supposed to factorize/simplify this but I'm really not sure what to do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: use partial fraction method or by dividing the two expressi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that $\int_{1}^{e}\frac{1+x^2\ln x}{x+x^2\ln x}dx=e-\ln (1+e)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993944/proving-that-int-1e-frac1x2-ln-xxx2-ln-xdx-e-ln-1e). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, add and subtract $x$ in the numerator. Then you can try the substitution $t=\ln x$.